# Problem with NFS server lockd timing out on Debian linux

Tags: linux, debian, nfs

We've recently upgraded an NFS server (called "ian"), and after the upgrade, NFS is broken, whereas it wasn't before.  The server is now running Debian "lenny", with kernel version 2.6.26-2; it's a truly ancient Dell PowerEdge 2650.  Here are the details of the problem as we've recorded them in our ticket system:

Here are some of the log messages on ian related to this:

kern.log:

```
Oct 7 10:37:50 ian kernel: [60831.093676] statd: server localhost not responding, timed out
Oct 7 10:37:50 ian kernel: [60831.093739] lockd: cannot monitor jade-30.example.com
Oct 7 10:38:20 ian kernel: [60871.021326] statd: server localhost not responding, timed out
Oct 7 10:38:20 ian kernel: [60871.021403] lockd: cannot monitor jade-30.example.com
Oct 7 10:38:50 ian kernel: [60913.065830] statd: server localhost not responding, timed out
Oct 7 10:38:50 ian kernel: [60913.065892] lockd: cannot monitor jade-30.example.com
Oct 7 10:39:20 ian kernel: [60956.671592] statd: server localhost not responding, timed out
Oct 7 10:39:20 ian kernel: [60956.671592] lockd: cannot monitor jade-30.example.com
Oct 7 10:39:50 ian kernel: [61000.167660] statd: server localhost not responding, timed out
Oct 7 10:39:50 ian kernel: [61000.167738] lockd: cannot unmonitor jade-43.example.com
Oct 7 10:40:20 ian kernel: [61046.297937] statd: server localhost not responding, timed out
Oct 7 10:40:20 ian kernel: [61046.298000] lockd: cannot unmonitor jade-48.example.com
Oct 7 10:40:50 ian kernel: [61097.378121] statd: server localhost not responding, timed out
Oct 7 10:40:50 ian kernel: [61097.378190] lockd: cannot unmonitor jade-56.example.com
Oct 7 10:41:20 ian kernel: [61140.563304] rpcbind: server jade-42.example.com not responding, timed out
Oct 7 10:41:20 ian kernel: [61140.566912] statd: server localhost not responding, timed out
Oct 7 10:41:20 ian kernel: [61140.566912] lockd: cannot monitor jade-30.example.com
Oct 7 10:41:20 ian kernel: [61140.563304] rpcbind: server jade-27.example.com not responding, timed out
Oct 7 10:41:50 ian kernel: [61185.324223] rpcbind: server jade-30.example.com not responding, timed out
Oct 7 10:41:50 ian kernel: [61185.324223] statd: server localhost not responding, timed out
Oct 7 10:41:50 ian kernel: [61185.324223] lockd: cannot monitor jade-30.example.com
[etc.]
```

daemon.log:

```
Oct 7 10:59:33 ian rpc.statd[3991]: Can't callback ian (100021,3), giving up.
[and many more]
```

(n.b. 100021 is the lockd RPC service.)

Shortly after then, this was in kern.log:

```
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] kernel BUG at kernel/workqueue.c:273!
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] <5>rpcbind: server jade-52.example.com not responding, timed out
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] SMP 
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] Modules linked in: ipmi_devintf ipmi_si ipmi_msghandler ppdev parport_pc lp parport ipv6 nfsd auth_rpcgss exportfs nfs lockd nfs_acl sunrpc dm_snapshot dm_mirror dm_log dm_mod snd_pcm snd_timer snd soundcore snd_page_alloc pcspkr shpchp pci_hotplug i2c_piix4 i2c_core button sworks_agp agpgart evdev dcdbas ext3 jbd mbcache sg sd_mod ide_cd_mod cdrom ata_generic libata dock ohci_hcd floppy aacraid usbcore tg3 scsi_mod e1000 serverworks ide_pci_generic ide_core thermal processor fan thermal_sys [last unloaded: scsi_wait_scan]
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] 
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] Pid: 3999, comm: rpciod/0 Not tainted (2.6.26-2-686 #1)
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] EIP: 0060:[<c012f0a0>] EFLAGS: 00010203 CPU: 0
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] EIP is at run_workqueue+0x66/0xf2
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] EAX: 00000000 EBX: f7de6f80 ECX: dd54f2dc EDX: dd54f2dc
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] ESI: dd54f2d8 EDI: f8b72afd EBP: 00000000 ESP: dec0bfac
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 00d8 GS: 0000 SS: 0068
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] Process rpciod/0 (pid: 3999, ti=dec0a000 task=f75595e0 task.ti=dec0a000)
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] Stack: f7de6f80 c012f789 f7de6f8c c012f83c 00000000 f75595e0 c0131a44 dec0bfc8 
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] dec0bfc8 f7de6f80 00000000 c0131983 c013194b 00000000 c01044f7 dd5bde04 
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] Call Trace:
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] [<c012f789>] worker_thread+0x0/0xbd
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] [<c012f83c>] worker_thread+0xb3/0xbd
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] [<c0131a44>] autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x2d
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] [<c0131983>] kthread+0x38/0x5d
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] [<c013194b>] kthread+0x0/0x5d
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] [<c01044f7>] kernel_thread_helper+0x7/0x10
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] =======================
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] Code: 7e 0c 89 73 18 8b 11 8b 41 04 89 42 04 89 10 89 49 04 89 09 f0 fe 03 fb 90 8d b4 26 00 00 00 00 90 8b 41 fc 83 e0 fc 39 d8 74 04 <0f> 0b eb fe f0 0f ba 71 fc 00 89 f0 ff d7 89 e0 25 00 e0 ff ff 
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.093217] EIP: [<c012f0a0>] run_workqueue+0x66/0xf2 SS:ESP 0068:dec0bfac
Oct 7 11:02:20 ian kernel: [62963.097562] ---[ end trace 661db88ca1ec8ada ]---
```

Given that the problem appears to have begun before this kernel bug was logged, it may not be the cause of the problem, or in fact related at all.  This kernel bug has only appeared this one time, even though the problem has reappeared after multiple reboots.

Although the problem began yesterday (and was presumably caused by the OS upgrade of ian the night before), it wasn't brought to our attention until today.

Some other debugging tests:

```
$ rpcinfo -p localhost
   program vers proto   port
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100021    1   udp  58030  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  58030  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  58030  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  52602  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  52602  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  52602  nlockmgr
    100024    1   udp  55130  status
    100024    1   tcp  36082  status
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100005    1   udp  60186  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  59282  mountd
    100005    2   udp  60186  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  59282  mountd
    100005    3   udp  60186  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  59282  mountd

$ rpcinfo -u localhost nlockmgr
rpcinfo: RPC: Timed out
program 100021 version 0 is not available
```

We found that after rebooting ian (which we did a few times) that NFS did actually work for a while. While it was working, the above command gave this output instead:

```
$ rpcinfo -u localhost nlockmgr
program 100021 version 1 ready and waiting
rpcinfo: RPC: Program/version mismatch; low version = 1, high version = 4
program 100021 version 2 is not available
program 100021 version 3 ready and waiting
program 100021 version 4 ready and waiting
```

We rebooted into the previous kernel (vmlinuz-2.6.20.6 from 2007-04-07), and we still had the problem.

We enabled debugging messages for the lockd/nlockmgr/nlm like this:
    # echo 2047 > /proc/sys/sunrpc/nlm_debug

The messages weren't obviously helpful. Here's from when NFS is working okay:

```
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037132] lockd: request from 192.168.246.17, port=896
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037151] lockd: LOCK_MSG called
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: nlm_lookup_host(192.168.240.55->192.168.246.17, p=17, v=4, my role=server, name=jade-45.example.com)
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: get host jade-45.example.com
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: LOCK called
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: nlm_lookup_host(192.168.240.55->192.168.246.17, p=17, v=4, my role=server, name=jade-45.example.com)
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: get host jade-45.example.com
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: nsm_monitor(jade-45.example.com)
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: nlm_lookup_file (01060001 fc22606e bd478947 777f518d 58ff17ac 028b086c 999bb476 00000000)
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: creating file for (01060001 fc22606e bd478947 777f518d 58ff17ac 028b086c 999bb476 00000000)
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: found file f5c21080 (count 0)
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: nlmsvc_lock(sda8/42666092, ty=1, pi=1886, 0-9223372036854775807, bl=1)
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: nlm_lookup_host(192.168.240.55->192.168.246.17, p=17, v=4, my role=server, name=jade-45.example.com)
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: get host jade-45.example.com
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: nlmsvc_lookup_block f=f5c21080 pd=1886 0-9223372036854775807 ty=1
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: get host jade-45.example.com
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: created block f6b882c0...
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: vfs_lock_file returned 0
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: freeing block f6b882c0...
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: release host jade-45.example.com
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: nlm_release_file(f5c21080, ct = 2)
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: release host jade-45.example.com
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: nlmsvc_lock returned 0
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: LOCK status 0
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: release host jade-45.example.com
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: nlm_release_file(f5c21080, ct = 1)
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: call procedure 12 on jade-45.example.com (async)
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: nlm_bind_host(192.168.240.55->192.168.246.17)
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: 20145 callback returned 0
Oct 8 15:45:12 ian kernel: [ 222.037171] lockd: release host jade-45.example.com
```

And the same thing from after lockd had failed to respond:

```
Oct 8 15:48:09 ian kernel: [ 461.693824] lockd: request from 192.168.246.96, port=940
Oct 8 15:48:09 ian kernel: [ 461.693901] lockd: LOCK_MSG called
Oct 8 15:48:09 ian kernel: [ 461.693974] lockd: nlm_lookup_host(192.168.240.55->192.168.246.96, p=17, v=4, my role=server, name=librarybrowser-06.local)
Oct 8 15:48:09 ian kernel: [ 461.694072] lockd: get host librarybrowser-06.local
Oct 8 15:48:09 ian kernel: [ 461.694142] lockd: LOCK called
Oct 8 15:48:09 ian kernel: [ 461.694212] lockd: nlm_lookup_host(192.168.240.55->192.168.246.96, p=17, v=4, my role=server, name=librarybrowser-06.local)
Oct 8 15:48:09 ian kernel: [ 461.694308] lockd: get host librarybrowser-06.local
Oct 8 15:48:09 ian kernel: [ 461.694377] lockd: nsm_monitor(librarybrowser-06.local)
Oct 8 15:48:09 ian kernel: [ 461.694448] lockd: nlm_lookup_file (01060001 fc22606e bd478947 777f518d 58ff17ac 027c0411 999bb54b 00000000)
Oct 8 15:48:09 ian kernel: [ 461.694543] lockd: creating file for (01060001 fc22606e bd478947 777f518d 58ff17ac 027c0411 999bb54b 00000000)
Oct 8 15:48:09 ian kernel: [ 461.694644] lockd: open failed (error 117440512)
Oct 8 15:48:09 ian kernel: [ 461.694713] lockd: release host librarybrowser-06.local
Oct 8 15:48:09 ian kernel: [ 461.694783] lockd: call procedure 12 on librarybrowser-06.local (async)
Oct 8 15:48:09 ian kernel: [ 461.694857] lockd: nlm_bind_host(192.168.240.55->192.168.246.96)
```

Note the "open failed (error 117440512)" line; we also got "open failed (error 16777216)"

It seems that the triggering of this failure may be load-related. After restarting NFS services, NFS continued to work for quite a while (but with few clients connecting as far 
as we could tell) before it failed again.

There's no firewall running on this server; /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny are both empty (except for comments).

We're currently at a dead end with this problem.  We don't have an easy way to go back to the pre-upgrade state.  However, we're accelerating our plans to migrate this service to a new server, but as that will be running more or less the same OS and kernel as the server that's currently having problems, it would be good to get a better idea of just what's causing the problem so we can have some confidence that we won't encounter them on the new server as well.

Any ideas, or tips for other things to investigate or try?

Thanks,

Tim.

Comment: Wild stab: does name resolution work for "localhost" and "ian" from ian?

Comment: Yes, name resolution is fine.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer to this here: http://sophiedogg.com/?p=141

- `/var/lib/nfs/statd/sm` - directory containing statd monitor list
- `/var/lib/nfs/statd/sm.bak` - directory containing statd notify list

Before removing these files, you should stop the rpcbind, statd, and lockd services. Below is a list of commands to run to fix this issue on a RPM based distro.

```
service rpcbind stop
service nfslock stop
rm -rf /var/lib/nfs/statd/sm/*
rm -rf /var/lib/nfs/statd/sm.bak/*
service rpcbind start
service nfslock start
```

After running these commands, it may be best to restart your NFS server.

In Debian and derivatives, the commands would be:

```
service nfs-kernel-server stop
service rpcbind stop
service nfs-common stop
service rpcbind start
service nfs-common start
service nfs-kernel-server start
```

I also did `service nfs-common restart` on the client just to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

the only thing I can tell you is that we have some NFS servers running lenny without any problems at all. The hardware is old (proliants g4, if I recall correctly, I am not at work now) but the disks are fast scsi 15krpm, so that's what basically matters.

Debugging nfs problems can be frustrating. I found that this helps you get more info from the logs:

```
* RPC debugging:
       echo 2048 > /proc/sys/sunrpc/rpc_debug
       grep . /proc/net/rpc/*/content
       ls -l /proc/fs/nfsd
       cat /proc/fs/nfs/exports 
* NFS debugging:
      # turn on linux nfs debug
      echo 1 > /proc/sys/sunrpc/nfs_debug
      # turn off linux nfs debug
      echo 0 > /proc/sys/sunrpc/nfs_debug
```