# Troubleshooting a kernel related lockup on CentOS

Tags: centos, nfs, kernel

I've got a bunch of desktop clients, that seem to be hanging periodically since updating kernel from `3.10.0-327` to `3.10.0-514` (`10.2`, `21.1` and `21.2`)

The only 'hard' evidence I get is occasionally I see events logged locally:

```
May 19 09:55:10 desktop-132 acpid: 1 client rule loaded
May 19 09:55:20 desktop-132 kernel: lockd: server nfserver not responding, still trying
May 19 09:55:23 desktop-132 kernel: lockd: server nfserver OK
May 19 09:55:23 desktop-132 gnome-session: (gnome-settings-daemon:3367): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: gdbusobjectmanagerclient.c:1586: Processing InterfaceRemoved signal for path /org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Device6 but no object proxy exists
May 19 09:55:23 desktop-132 gnome-session: (gnome-settings-daemon:3367): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: gdbusobjectmanagerclient.c:1586: Processing InterfaceRemoved signal for path /org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Device7 but no object proxy exists
May 19 09:55:23 desktop-132 gnome-session: (gnome-settings-daemon:3367): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: gdbusobjectmanagerclient.c:1586: Processing InterfaceRemoved signal for path /org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Device8 but no object proxy exists
May 19 09:55:23 desktop-132 gnome-session: (gnome-settings-daemon:3367): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: gdbusobjectmanagerclient.c:1586: Processing InterfaceRemoved signal for path /org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Device9 but no object proxy exists
May 19 09:55:23 desktop-132 gnome-session: (gnome-settings-daemon:3367): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: gdbusobjectmanagerclient.c:1586: Processing InterfaceRemoved signal for path /org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Device10 but no object proxy exists
May 19 09:55:23 desktop-132 gnome-session: Window manager warning: last_user_time (946497320) is greater than comparison timestamp (946495968).  This most likely represents a buggy client sending inaccurate timestamps in messages such as _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW.  Trying to work around...
May 19 09:55:23 desktop-132 gnome-session: Window manager warning: 0x2000007 (user@d) appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 946497320.  Working around...
```

I am pretty sure that this problem is only being encountered on this kernel version - only stuff that's been updated is showing it, and *downgrading* to 3.10.0-327 again makes the problem go away.

Of course, that's not a help, because we're updating because of security fixes.

The problem still seems to be present on the current kernel version released just a couple of days ago.

But I'm at something of a loss - I've got nothing being logged, just 'lockups' that I'm trying to track. So I've not even got the basics I need to start filing a bug report.

Comment: Are you using NTP or similar to sync time? Also, is the NFS server scaled appropriately for the number of clients?

Comment: We are ntp syncing, and checking jitter (it's low). NFS server is a 12 node Isilon, and comfortable with the number of clients.

Comment: Hmm, maybe try things from https://serverfault.com/questions/188918/problem-with-nfs-server-lockd-timing-out-on-debian-linux or https://access.redhat.com/solutions/28211 ?